# Correct YAML syntax from frontmatter

Tags: yaml, netlify-cms, yaml-front-matter

I need to achieve this frontmatter:

```
    services:
      - service:
        serviceName: Service 1
        serviceDesc: Blah
      - service:
        serviceName: Service 2
        serviceDesc: Blah
      - service:
        serviceName: Service 3
        serviceDesc: Blah
```

Here is my current Yaml syntax:

```
    services:
      service:
        - serviceName: Water Treatment
          serviceDesc: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
            eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        - serviceName: Environmental Services
          serviceDesc: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing eliy, sed do
            eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
```

I am using Netlify CMS to create this but I cannot find a solution to get an individual `service` to use with Nunjucks.

Any help would be amazing.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your `config.yml` file would help, but from the look of your current output, I will assume that it looks something like this:

```yaml
- label: 'Services'
  name: 'services'
  widget: 'object'
  fields:
    - label: 'Service'
      name: 'service'
      widget: 'list'
      fields:
        - { label: 'Name', name: 'serviceName', widget: string }
        - { label: 'Description', name: 'serviceDesc', widget: text }
```

In you case, you want the `service` node to be one level lower, wrapping each list element, so you should be able to just switch the position of your `object` and `list` widgets like so:

```yaml
- label: 'Services'
  name: 'services'
  widget: 'list'
  fields:
    - label: 'Service'
      name: 'service'
      widget: 'object'
      fields:
        - { label: 'Name', name: 'serviceName', widget: string }
        - { label: 'Description', name: 'serviceDesc', widget: text }
```